# how to communicate with socket on azure virtual machine?

Tags: sockets, azure

I had developed a socket on python that is work fine on physical machines , as I communicate with specific port number that is hard coded in my program (Python) that is 9070.Whenever execute this python socket on azure virtual machine or cloud service with worker role , cannot communicate with this socket.I am new to networking, i'll really appreciated if someone lead me to right point .

The error I found on client side is

> TCP connection time out

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you need to open up an endpoint to that port on your VM. You can find instructions here: [Set up endpoints on a Virtual Machine](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/)

Comment: yes i add an endpoint through virtual machine endpoints  by button "Add"....but there is only 2 ports are open that is remote desktop and powershell, not any port open that i added after,  i checked using [link](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)

Comment: see below attached image....it will be clear what i want to say????http://postimg.org/image/vmpfepsdn/

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your endpoints? Also, make sure the VM itself has the port opened on it's firewall. What OS are you running?

Comment: i'm running windows sever 2012 R2 data center,  i allow the port from firewall  inbound rules as same as other port configured that is(rdp and powershell) rules but when i ping this configured port through psping "connection to the network failed", but rdp and powershell psping reply successfully....and i'm really sory for my weak english !! below is my endpoints image link ---> [link](http://postimg.org/image/3ponkn1bv/)

Comment: but when i configured iis server

Comment: but when i configured iis server steps i followed...1) in azure portal i add an endpoint with the name "Web" and public and private port  8080 and 80 repectively!! and then i check this 8080 port on portchecker as a result port is open successfully! i does not add any inbound rule in firewall for 8080!!  tell me the way to allow port successfully ?